# How can I put a "+" below each table?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/produits-game/

Under each table I want to put a "+" as in this example

http://www.delumine.ch/produits-et-gamme.html

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xcn8fg94/

CODE HTML:

```
 <div id="tabel_1">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>


</div>

<div id="tabel_2">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>


</div>

<div id="tabel_3">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>


</div>

<div id="tabel_4">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>


</div>
```

Code CSS:

```
  #tabel_1,#tabel_2,#tabel_3,#tabel_4{width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        vertical-align:top;
        border: 2px solid #264572;
        margin-left: 10px;}
```

I tried to add `<p>+<p>` under each table but not working.

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add <p>+</p>

Comment: can you give me an example please?i tried to do this but doesn`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a margin below the divs (margin-bottom)
2. Make the div positioned absolute, so that the p containing the + can be positioned absolute
3. Create the p , with class bottom
4. Give them the correct dimension and position

```css
#tabel_1,#tabel_2,#tabel_3,#tabel_4{width:210px;height:540px;
     display:inline-block;
     background: #FFFFFF;
        vertical-align:top;
     border: 2px solid #264572;
     margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabel_1">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>
    <p class="bottom">+</p>
</div>

<div id="tabel_2">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>
    <p class="bottom">+</p>
</div>

<div id="tabel_3">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>
    <p class="bottom">+</p>
</div>

<div id="tabel_4">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
   <div id="image_first"></div>
    <p class="bottom">+</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But your site seems ok to me ??

Answer (score 0):

you probably wouldnt use the + as in what is on your keyboard. check out icon websites like http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/. through font-awesome they have different sizes and they are very easy to use.
for the full icon list go here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a :after selector for that and set an icon as the background. Currently not on my pc, so no example sorry.

Comment: If needed ill add an example tomorrow.

Comment: please i need an example...ok,tomorrow

Comment: i put #tabel_1::after{content:"+";}  but he is still displayed inside the table